# How to configure vite.config.js to work with node js backend

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs3, vite

I am practicing both backend and frontend, I am using express and vue 3.
I am trying to display images came from backend to frontend, but it still listen to the port of my frontend, i already tried to clear cache in my browser and also try to run it in different browser, however i still get error 404 since the request URL still localhost of my frontend.

Here's my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8000',
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
      '/images/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    basedir: './',
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

here's my setting in backend,
this works. because i tried to view it in browser
and run "localhost:8000/images/basil-bottle.webp"

```
app.use(express.json());
    await clientCon.connect();
    const db = clientCon.db('SystemTestDB');
    app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../assets")));
    
    app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
        const products = await db.collection('products').find({}).toArray();
        res.json(products);
    })
```

here's my views

```
<template>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <ProductList :result="result"></ProductList>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import ProductList from '../components/ProductList.vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const result = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/products');
    result.value = response.data
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
</script>
```

and this is my component

```
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        result: Array
    })
</script>
<template>
    <div class="grid-wrap">
        <div class="product-item" v-for="product in result" :key="product.id">
            
            <img :src="product.imageUrl" alt="bottle images"/>
            <h3 class="product-name">{{ product.name }}</h3>
            <p class="product-price">{{ product.price }}</p>
            <RouterLink :to="`details/${product.id}`">
                <button> View details </button>
            </RouterLink>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

so when i hover it to the image src in devtools it shows "localhost:5173/images/basil-bottle.webp"
which is the port of my frontend and it should be port 8000.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what exactly is the problem? the images are not showing up? you can also add more configurations - how you configured the base url for your `axios`, your express `app.js` file for the base api setup

Comment: @Airah yes, the image is the only one that is not showing. other details is displaying.

Comment: what does your axios config look like? from your screenshots, it looks like the base URL has not been configured to be `localhost:8000`, so by default, axios will use the url of your frontend, which is `localhost:5173`. so you need to configure your axios instance

Comment: @Airah i think i did not configure my axios? i just installed it and use it right away...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `axios` is not configured to use the URL for your backend.
Axios is what's responsible for making the API calls so you need to configure the base url correctly.

An example of that would look like this:

**axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';    

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

Then, you can now use Axios anywhere in your app using the `axiosInstance`.
So your request should look like this:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import ProductList from '../components/ProductList.vue';
import axiosInstance from './axios.js'; //make sure to import the file correctly

const result = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get('/api/products');
    result.value = response.data
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
</script>
```

That should fix the image url.

**EDIT:** Ensure your API is also configured to allow requests from origins like your frontend URL, install the `cors` module and use in your API config. file like below:

```
app.use(express.json());

// add these
const cors = require('cors');

const allowedOrigins = [
  "http://localhost:5173", //your frontend URL
  // any other origins you want to allow
]

const corsOptions = {
  origin: allowedOrigins
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//the rest of your code
await clientCon.connect();
const db = clientCon.db('SystemTestDB');
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../assets")));

app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await db.collection('products').find({}).toArray();
    res.json(products);
})
```

Comment: may i ask which document should i add the configuration of axios?

Comment: @Awoooooooooooooooooooo you can give it any name like `axios.js` and import correctly. Updated the answer to give an example

Comment: it gives now an error says Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: it's sending the right request now. the new error is coming from your backend, it's not configured to allow requests from `localhost:5173`, so you need to to configure your API correctly. @Awoooooooooooooooooooo 
I've edited the answer to solve the new issue

Comment: this works now! really appreciate it!