Vite frontend is not making API call to server properly
I am using Vite React, from frontend which is running on localhost:3000, if I make an API call to backend which on localhost:5000, frontend always make a API call at port 3000 instead of 500.

below is how my code looks:
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,  // Frontend runs on port 3000
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000/',  // Backend running on port 5000
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});


// Login.jsx

const LoginAdmin = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Email is required'),
      password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
    }),
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/admin/login', values);
        alert('Login successful!');
        console.log(response.data);
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error);
        alert('Invalid credentials or account not active/approved.');
      }
    },
  });

  return ()
};



// server.js

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // Allow requests from frontend
    credentials: true,  // Allow sending cookies or authentication tokens
  }));
app.use(express.json());

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();
// Use admin routes
app.use('/api/admin', adminRoutes);

// Basic route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from the ES6 backend, DB connected');
});

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

I checked form and Axios request are set up correctly. Also ensured the backend endpoint exists and is correctly handling the request. Also verified the proxy configuration in vite.config.js.

What's the problem? Yes the requests go to :3000; that is where you (explicitly and absolutely, although they could and should be relative). Then they get proxied to :5000. You shouldn't need CORS handling at all; that's the whole point of the proxy.

@jonrsharpe can you plz help in simple terms, it will be great help,
i remove CORS part still give same error

Does this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77209492/how-to-configure-vite-config-js-to-work-with-node-js-backend/77209600#77209600

what does the error have to do with login.jsx?

perhaps whatever adminRoutes is doesn't have a /register POST route? Also, you've shown code that tries /api/admin/login rather than the /api/admin/register - so, that is quite useless code to show

@JaromandaX adminRoutes have both /register and/login route, and /api/admin/login and /api/admin/register both give same error

and this is an issue when you run npm run dev?

I understand this is not a solution, but first of all can u try appending the host url during the api call if that works. const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/admin/login', values);
